# Use Induction to prove recurrence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recurrence-relations

[image: question screenshot]

if the above screenshot is not visible, here is the text format:

Question:

Solve the following recurrence and prove your result is correct using induction:

$a_1 = 0$

$a_n = 3(a_{n-1}) + 4^{n}$ for $n>=2$

---

Use induction to prove this recursive sequence.
So my approach was that, I plug in the $a_1 = 0$ into $a_2 = 3(0) + 4^{2} = 4^{2}$

and then

$a_3 = 3(4^{2}) + 4^{3}$

$a_4 = 3(3(4^{2}) + 4^{3}) + 4^{4} = 3^{2} *4^{2} + 3 * 4^{3} +4^{4}$

$a_5 = 3(3^{2} *4^{2} + 3 * 4^{3} +4^{4}) + 4^{5} = 3^{3} *4^{2} + 3^{2} * 4^{3} +3*4^{4} + 4^{5}$

$a_6 = 3^{4} *4^{2} + 3^{3} * 4^{3} +3^{2}*4^{4} + 3*4^{5} + 4^{6}$

...

$a_n = 3^{n-2} *4^{2} + 3^{n-3} * 4^{3} + ... + 3*4^{n-1} + 4^{n} = \sum_{k=2}^{n} 3^{n-k}*4^{k} $

now through induction, I'm not sure how to get there. So far what I know is that:

$a_{n+1} = 3(a_{n}) + 4^{n+1} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} 3^{n+1-k}*4^{k}$

= $3(\sum_{k=2}^{n} 3^{n-k}*4^{k}) + 4^{n+1} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} 3^{n+1-k}*4^{k}$

= $(\sum_{k=2}^{n} 3*3^{n-k}*4^{k}) + 4^{n+1} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} 3^{n+1-k}*4^{k}$

= $(\sum_{k=2}^{n} 3^{n+1-k}*4^{k}) + 4^{n+1} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} 3^{n+1-k}*4^{k}$

but then I'm stuck, because I cannot simplify it to make them equal to each other, or I'm in the wrong direction?

Comment: Did you mean $a_1=0$ for the sequence definition?

Comment: Also what exactly is it you're trying to prove for all $n$?

Comment: @Angelica Hi yes, sorry, my mistake, I just updated, that was for $a_1$ not $a_0$. So I'm trying to use induction to prove that $a_n = 3_{a-1} + 4^{n}$ is valid for all n>=2

Comment: I am sorry, but the first two sentences in your question still make no sense.  That is, you are apparently defining a sequence by a precise specification, and then are trying to prove that the specification holds (i.e. "Use induction to prove this recursive sequence").  Please re-read and edit your question, in an effort to make it **crystal clear** what premise is given and then what conclusion must be proven, based on the premise.

Comment: @123456 I would check if you are understanding the exercise correct. Because if you are calculating the values of $(a_n)$ with this formula then the formula is valid for the sequence you get.

Comment: By the way, re my previous comment, if you are given a premise, and wish to prove a conclusion by induction, you can limit your analysis to establishing that the conclusion holds for a base case $(n =B)$, and then showing that if the conclusion holds for $(n = N \geq B)$, then the conclusion also holds for $(n = N+1)$.  That is, you normally don't need to consider any explicit computations other than at $(n = B), (n = N \geq B),$ and $(n = N + 1).$

Comment: Note further, that the most common approaches, for this type of problem are a consideration of either $\displaystyle (a_{n+1} - a_n)$ or $\displaystyle \left[\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right].$

Comment: It seems you're there already. Your first line: $$a_{n+1} = 3(a_{n}) + 4^{n+1} = \sum_{k=2}^{n+1} 3^{n+1-k}*4^{k}$$ is your proof, since you assume the formula for $a_n$ and, by applying the recurrence,  find that your formula is valid for $a_{n+1}$. All you need is to add a couple of explanatory steps.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a useful "trick".

If
$a_n
=ua_{n-1}+v^n
$
then
(here comes the trick),
dividing by $u^n$,
$\dfrac{a_n}{u^n}
=\dfrac{ua_{n-1}}{u^n}+\dfrac{v^n}{u^n}
=\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{u^{n-1}}+(v/u)^n
$.

Let $b_n = \dfrac{a_n}{u^n}$.
Then
$b_n
=b_{n-1}+r^n
$
where $r = v/u$
or
$b_n-b_{n-1}
=r^n
$.

This becomes a telescoping sum,
so

$\begin{array}\\
b_m-b_0
&=\sum_{n=1}^m (b_n-b_{n-1})\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^m r^n\\
&=\dfrac{r-r^{m+1}}{1-r}
\qquad\text{(if } r \ne 1.
\text{ If }r=1, \text{the sum is }m.)\\
&=\dfrac{\frac{v}{u}-(\frac{v}{u})^{m+1}}{1-\frac{v}{u}}\\
&=\dfrac{v-\frac{v^{m+1}}{u^m}}{u-v}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{a_m}{u^m}-a_0
&=\dfrac{v-\frac{v^{m+1}}{u^m}}{u-v}\\
\text{or}\\
a_m
&=u^ma_0+\dfrac{vu^m-v^{m+1}}{u-v}\\
&=u^ma_0+\dfrac{v(u^m-v^{m})}{u-v}\\
\end{array}
$

Note that,
if the $a$s start at $k$
instead of $0$,
we can do

$\begin{array}\\
b_m-b_k
&=\sum_{n=k+1}^m (b_n-b_{n-1})\\
&=\sum_{n=k+1}^m r^n\\
&=\dfrac{r^{k+1}-r^{m+1}}{1-r}
\qquad\text{(if } r \ne 1.
\text{ If }r=1, \text{the sum is }m-k.)\\
&=\dfrac{(\frac{v}{u})^{k+1}-(\frac{v}{u})^{m+1}}{1-\frac{v}{u}}\\
&=\dfrac{\frac{v^{k+1}}{u^k}-\frac{v^{m+1}}{u^m}}{u-v}\\
\text{so}\\
\dfrac{a_m}{u^m}-\dfrac{a_k}{u^k}
&=\dfrac{\frac{v^{k+1}}{u^k}-\frac{v^{m+1}}{u^m}}{u-v}\\
\text{or}\\
a_m
&=u^{m-k}a_k+\dfrac{v^{k+1}u^{m-k}-v^{m+1}}{u-v}\\
&=u^{m-k}a_k+\dfrac{v^{k+1}(u^{m-k}-v^{m-k})}{u-v}\\
\end{array}
$

If this is for
$k=1$,
this becomes
$a_m
=u^{m-1}a_1+\dfrac{v^{2}(u^{m-1}-v^{m-1})}{u-v}
$.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean $a_0=0$ and $a_n = 3a_{n-1}+4^n$ for $n\ge 1$ (not $n\ge 2$). And by "prove this recursive sequence", you mean to find a closed formula.

Consider the generating function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$,

then by the initial condition and recursive relation, we have $$3xf(x)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4^nx^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n = f(x)$$

$$3xf(x) + \frac{1}{1-4x}-1=f(x)$$

$$\begin{align} f(x) &= \frac{4x}{(1-4x)(1-3x)} =4x(\sum_{a=0}^\infty (4x)^a)(\sum_{b=0}^\infty (3x)^b) \\ &=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4(\sum_{a+b=n-1}4^a3^b)x^n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4 \sum_{b=0}^{n-1}(\frac{3}{4})^b 4^{n-1} x^n\\&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 4^{n+1}(1-(\frac{3}{4})^n)x^n\end{align}$$

Hence $a_n = 4^{n+1}(1-(\frac{3}{4})^n)=4(4^n-3^n)$.

The above reasoning is solid. But if you prefer, you may prove this by induction.